# Azure WebAPI auhorization Steps

Tags: azure, authentication, authorization, owin

I wanted to implement Authorization in my `Web API`, to achieve the same I have done below :

1. created and deployed webapi on azure portal .
2. registered my application in Azure AD
3. Defined application level role through manifest
4. Created Client and client secret

I placed an `Authorize` attribute on the top of my API method in controller:

```
  [Authorize(Roles = "ApplicationOwner")]
        public String Index()
        {
            return "Testing based on role";
        }
```

But this code is not working.

I wanted to authorize the same by using `OWIN` ... I tried to call the `Web API` method using client without sending bearer token, but my method is getting called every time.

Please help me on steps to authorize the same.

Below are the startup Code :-

app.UseCors(Microsoft.Owin.Cors.CorsOptions.AllowAll);

```
        var OAuthOptions = new OAuthAuthorizationServerOptions
        {
            AllowInsecureHttp = true,
            TokenEndpointPath = new PathString("/oauth/Token"),
            AccessTokenExpireTimeSpan = TimeSpan.FromHours(8),
            Provider = new Providers.MyAuthorizationServerProvider(),

        app.UseOAuthAuthorizationServer(OAuthOptions);
        app.UseOAuthBearerAuthentication(new OAuthBearerAuthenticationOptions());

        var config = new HttpConfiguration();

        config.SuppressDefaultHostAuthentication();
        config.Filters.Add(new 
         HostAuthenticationFilter(OAuthDefaults.AuthenticationType));

        config.MapHttpAttributeRoutes();


        app.UseWebApi(config);
```

I am getting error 401 every time while i am sending proper role in bearer token .My requirement is to create secure webapi which will be accessible if consumer send bearer token in request header .

public class ApplicationOAuthProvider : OAuthAuthorizationServerProvider
    {
        private readonly string _publicClientId;

```
    public ApplicationOAuthProvider()
    {

    }

    public override async Task GrantResourceOwnerCredentials(OAuthGrantResourceOwnerCredentialsContext context)
    {


        var identity = new ClaimsIdentity(context.Options.AuthenticationType);
         identity.AddClaim(new Claim(ClaimTypes.Role, "Application_Approver"));


        identity.AddClaim(new Claim(ClaimTypes.Name, context.UserName));
        identity.AddClaim(new Claim(ClaimTypes.Role, "Admin"));


        AuthenticationProperties properties = CreateProperties("Application_Approver");
        AuthenticationTicket ticket = new AuthenticationTicket(identity, properties);
        context.Validated(ticket);
    }
    public override async Task ValidateClientAuthentication(OAuthValidateClientAuthenticationContext context)
    {

        context.Validated();
    }
    public override Task TokenEndpoint(OAuthTokenEndpointContext context)
    {
        foreach (KeyValuePair<string, string> property in context.Properties.Dictionary)
        {
            context.AdditionalResponseParameters.Add(property.Key, property.Value);
        }

        return Task.FromResult<object>(null);
    }


    public static AuthenticationProperties CreateProperties(string userName, string Roles)
    {
        IDictionary<string, string> data = new Dictionary<string, string>
    {

        {"roles",Roles}
    };
        return new AuthenticationProperties(data);
    }
```

Comment: Can you please share the OWIN authentication configuration and the error message you are getting?

Comment: Hi Navya ... I have added owin config code and error (401) ....